# Data clearing when using Target to update range

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have the following macro

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Target.Parent.Range("D31")
If Target.Address <> rng.Address Then Exit Sub
Select Case rng.Value
        Case "N/A": Result = "N/A"
        Case "NA": Result = "N/A"
        Case "": Result = ""
End Select
Range("E31, G31, H31, I31, J31, K31") = Result
End Sub
```

When I initially type a value in D31 that is not NA and then type a value in E31, I see the data in E31. But if I update D31 (i.e. original value red, new vale read and blue), the value in E31 is erased. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Which event is this code in?

Comment: I think it's in `Worksheet_Change` event.

Answer (score 0):

1. I put `Range("E31, G31, H31, I31, J31, K31") = Result` inside a condition
   `If Target.Value = "" Or Result <> ""`.
2. Also, removed `rng` variable which seems not needed.

```vb
If Target <> Range("D31") Then Exit Sub
Select Case Target.Value
        Case "N/A": Result = "N/A"
        Case "NA": Result = "N/A"
        Case "": Result = ""
End Select
If Target.Value = "" Or Result <> "" Then
  Range("E31, G31, H31, I31, J31, K31") = Result
End If
```

Now values `E31, G31, H31, I31, J31, K31` only change when you input "N/A", "NA" or "" into `D31`.